# How to get the following dictionary in tne easiest way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I get a list here:

```
my_list=["Alex:1990:London", 
         "Tony:1993:NYC", 
         "Kate:2001:Beijing", 
         "Tony:2001:LA", 
         "Alex:1978:Shanghai"]
```

How can I get the target dictionary *my_target_dict* from *my_list* in the easiest way?

```
my_target_dict={
                "Alex":["Alex:1990:London", "Alex:1978:Shanghai"], 
                "Tony":["Tony:1993:NYC", "Tony:2001:LA"], 
                "Kate":["Kate:2001:Beijing"]
               }
```

Comment: If there is only one item you want it to be just the item? consider that it makes all a lot more inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_list=["Alex:1990:London", "Tony:1993:NYC", "Kate:2001:Beijing", "Tony:2001:LA", "Alex:1978:Shanghai"]
>>> d =  defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in my_list:
...     name, *_ = item.partition(":")
...     d[name].append(item)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Alex': ['Alex:1990:London', 'Alex:1978:Shanghai'], 'Tony': ['Tony:1993:NYC', 'Tony:2001:LA'], 'Kate': ['Kate:2001:Beijing']})
>>> d["Alex"]
['Alex:1990:London', 'Alex:1978:Shanghai']
```

You can use this comprehension to clean the list wrapped single items:

```
>>> {k:v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] for k,v in d.items()}
{'Alex': ['Alex:1990:London', 'Alex:1978:Shanghai'], 'Tony': ['Tony:1993:NYC', 'Tony:2001:LA'], 'Kate': 'Kate:2001:Beijing'}
```

Comment: And if you want to make it just a regular dict afterward you can do `d=dict(d)`

Comment: @piglot, you are welcome :) Please consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In case you intend to work strictly with lists and dictionaries alone, try this:

```
my_target_dict=dict()
for value in my_list:
    key=value.split(':')[0]
    if key in my_target_dict:
        my_target_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        my_target_dict[key]=[value]
 print(my_target_dict)
```

Comment: The *my_target_dict* is what I want...you cannot use it before it created

Comment: The dictionary _my_target_dict_ is being used after creation. The first line of code creates an empty dictionary, and then items are added to it using a 'for` loop on _my_list_

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner (as I see) and don't want to use Python's **collections** module and do the implementation from scratch (it's imp to understand the concept of background work which **collection** does).

> Once you are familiar with this, you can go with **collections** module and that is beautiful as it has many classes like `defaultdict`, `OrderedDict` etc. which can boost the speed of your work.

Here is what I have tried (do not forget to read the commented lines).

> I have written a function named **get_my_target_dict()** which takes **my_list** and returns **my_target_dict**. And this is the modular implemenation (that you should prefer).
>
> **re** is a module to work with regular expressions. Here it is used to match *"Alex:  1990  : London"* (i.e. spaces around **:**) kind of strings if any (by mistake).

```
import re

def get_my_target_dict(my_list):
    my_target_dict = {} # dictionary

    for string in my_list:
        # "Alex:1990:London" => ["Alex", "1990", "London"]
        # "Alex :   1990: London" => ["Alex", "1990", "London"]
        items = re.split(r"\s*:\s*", string) # `\s*` is to match spaces around `:`
        print(items)

        # Alex, Tony etc.
        key = items[0]

        if key in my_target_dict:
            my_target_dict[key].append(string)
        else:
            my_target_dict[key] = [string]

    return my_target_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list=["Alex:1990:London", 
             "Tony:1993:NYC", 
             "Kate:2001:Beijing", 
             "Tony:2001:LA", 
             "Alex:1978:Shanghai"]

    # Call get_my_target_dict(), pass my_list & get my_target_dict
    my_target_dict = get_my_target_dict(my_list)
    print(my_target_dict)
    # {'Alex': ['Alex:1990:London', 'Alex:1978:Shanghai'], 'Tony': ['Tony:1993:NYC', 'Tony:2001:LA'], 'Kate': ['Kate:2001:Beijing']}

    # Pretty printing dictionary
    import json
    print(json.dumps(my_target_dict, indent=4))
    # {
    #     "Alex": [
    #         "Alex:1990:London",
    #         "Alex:1978:Shanghai"
    #     ],
    #     "Tony": [
    #         "Tony:1993:NYC",
    #         "Tony:2001:LA"
    #     ],
    #     "Kate": [
    #         "Kate:2001:Beijing"
    #     ]
    # }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for you:

```
my_list=["Alex:1990:London", "Tony:1993:NYC", "Kate:2001:Beijing", "Tony:2001:LA", "Alex:1978:Shanghai"]
dict = {}
for idx, content in enumerate(my_list):
    name = content[:(content.index(':'))]
    if name not in dict:
        dict[name] = []
    dict[name].append(my_list[idx])
```

1. First if you don't know about `enumerate`, it count your index and
   take the content in each element of list.
2. Second, take name of there people by basic python of string. I use `name = content[:(content.index(':'))]` in order to take string from start to the first symbol ":".
3. Third, check if the key of `dict` exist or not. Otherwise, it will delete all your element in list of that key.
4. Last but not least, append the element you want into your key dict.

Your finally result:

```
{'Alex': ['Alex:1990:London', 'Alex:1978:Shanghai'], 'Tony': ['Tony:1993:NYC', 'Tony:2001:LA'], 'Kate': ['Kate:2001:Beijing']}
```